# SQL query using SET operator

Tags: sql, oracle

Using a SET command, show all the countries in region 1 that do not have a location.
Display only the country_id.

This is my query and it's wrong. I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT c.country_id
FROM Countries c
WHERE r.region_id = 1
MINUS
SELECT c2.country_id
FROM Countries c2
WHERE l.location_id IS NULL;
```

[image]

Comment: Why you have used `l.location_id`? It should be `c2.location_id`.and also it should be `c.region_id` instead of `r.region_id`

Comment: its confusing me because the location_id is not in the Countries table, its in the Locations table

Comment: And what about region_id? Please share the structure of all related tables, Sample data and expected output.

Comment: yeah you are right its c.region_id

Comment: What is the mapping between location and country table?  Mapping is in location table?

Comment: I added the image on the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `country` and `location` table as follows:

```
SELECT c.country_id
FROM Countries c
WHERE c.region_id = 1
MINUS
SELECT c2.country_id
FROM location c2;
```